# Unable to get the right answer through convolution in z transform

Tags: z-transform

Through the method of convolution, I found that the inverse z transform of 
$$\frac{z^2}{(z-2)^2}$$
as $2^{n} \, (n+1)$.

But, when I try to use the same formula of convolution to find the inverse of
$$\frac{z}{(z-2)^2}$$
I get the answer as $2^{n-1} \, (n+1)$ while the correct answer is $2^{n-1} \, n$.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different method to see how it works. Consider the series
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$ 
which, by differentiation, 
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \, x^{n-1}.$$
Now multiply the last equation by $x$ to obtain
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \, x^{n}.$$
Now, to be seen as the required z-transform set $x = 2/z$ to obtain the following result.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n} \, n \, z^{-n} = \frac{2}{z} \, \frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{2}{z}\right)^2} = \frac{2 \, z}{(z-2)^2} $$
or
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n-1} \, n \, z^{-n} = \frac{z}{(z-2)^2}.$$